# How did Newcomen's Atmospheric Engine lift water above the 10.3m vacuum limit?

Tags: engineering

I've been reading about Newcomen's engine but i'm not clear on how he overcame the lift limit due to gravity on the water column overcoming the suction of the partial vacuum.  Did the engine somehow create a continual positive pressure and if so how?

Thanks

Comment: From your question you seem to have some misunderstandings of (a) how the engine works, and (b) the relationship between the engine and the pump doing the work. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The engine in question does not *lift* water; rather it *pushes* water up from the bottom of the vessel.  As is clearly shown in the animated image [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newcomen_atmospheric_engine), condensed steam is forced into the bottom of the lifting pipe.  A freeze-frame from that page:
[image]

So long as the combination of partial vacuum in the cylinder (as steam condenses into liquid) and the net mass (weight) of the piston-linkage assembly is sufficient to overcome the pressure on the outlet valve, the machine will pump water into the upper chamber.